# Python OS get current File name on imported module

Tags: python

I am trying to write a logging module that I can use over and over again. The logging is not the problem. I want to call my logging module from any script and not have to pass the params for the logging file.

If I have a test script called mytest.py how would I return this name in the import logging module. I have tried this in the logging script itself but it returns the name of that file and not the file I am trying to log.

```
my_test.py:

from my_logger  import logging

info.logging("something here")
print("something here")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging()
```

I would expect the log file to be called my_test.log, but currently it is being named logging.log

Here is the part from the logging script:

```
def logging(filename=False, level=DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL):
    if filename is False:
        file_ext = os.path.basename(__file__) # Need this to be my_test.py
        filename = ("C:/Users/Logs/{0}").format(file_ext)
        "Start logging with given filename and level."
        #print(filename)
        logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=LEVELS[level])
    else:
        "Start logging with given filename and level."
        logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=LEVELS[level])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your compiler is CPython (*thanks to [Matthew Trevor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11265/matthew-trevor)*);

You can use [inspect.getouterframes](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getouterframes) to get the caller's frame, plus the filename and line number etc.

```
import inspect

def logging(filename=False, level=DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL):
    if filename is False:
        caller_file = inspect.getouterframes(inspect.currentframe())[1][3] 
        # prints /home/foo/project/my_test.py
    ...
```

Comment: It's possibly important to note that is may be implementation dependent and shouldn't be relied on outside of CPython.

Answer (score 0):

The `__file__` binding you use in your `logging` function will hold the value of the file it's scoped in. You need to pass in the calling module's `__file__` to get the behaviour you want:

```
# my_test.py

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging(__file__)
```

I'm surprised that your log file was called `logging.log` and not `my_logger.log`, though, as that's the name of the file in which the `logging` function is defined.

Comment: First parameter of his `logging` method takes a boolean value not the file itself. He probably wants to get the file of the caller of this method.

Comment: No, the first parameter is initially set `False`, but if it's passed a non-empty string it'll use that instead. Non-empty strings are considered to be `True` by Python conditions.

Comment: In my humble opinion, `None` instead of `False` would be much meaningful as the default value of the parameter.

Comment: Perhaps, but that's not the issue at hand.